# Filter product flavors with beforeVariants API in gradle Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle

I've the following `productFlavors` setup:

```kotlin
productFlavors {
        create("gamma") {
            dimension = "build"
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
            applicationIdSuffix = ".gamma"
        }
        create("prod") {
            dimension = "build"
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to filter our prodDebug (as it appears in Build Variants selection menu in Android Studio):

```kotlin
androidComponents {
    beforeVariants { variantBuilder ->
        if ((variantBuilder.name == "prod") &&
            (variantBuilder.buildType == "debug")
        ) {
            variantBuilder.enable = false
        }
    }
}
```

however, this seems to fail as `prodDebug` still shows under Build Variants in Android Studio (Iguana):

[image: proddebug-buildvariants-androidstudio]

Any hints on how to exclude prodDebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```kotlin
androidComponents {
    beforeVariants { variantBuilder ->
        if ((variantBuilder.flavorName == "prod") &&
            (variantBuilder.buildType == "debug")
        ) {
            variantBuilder.enable = false
        }
    }
}
```